# Resize image using php Imagemagick

Tags: php, imagemagick

Im trying to resize an image using imagemagick's function 'thumbnailImage'. Right now, im not doing anything with image afterwards, just echoing the new dimensions to see if it worked. And so far, it isnt working. Heres my code. NOTE: it does echo the original dimensions, just not the new ones.

```
$image = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

//Get original dimensions
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($image);
echo "<BR>";
echo "ORIGINAL:";
echo "<BR>";
echo "Image width $width";
echo "<BR>";
echo "Image height " .$height;



  $max_height = 200;
    $max_width = 150;

 function thumbnail($image, $max_width, $max_height) {
        $img = new Imagick($image);
        $img->thumbnailImage($max_width, $max_height, TRUE);
        return $img;
    }
thumbnail($image, $max_width, $max_height);

//get new dimensions
    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($img);
    echo "<BR>";
    echo "NEW:";
    echo "<BR>";
    echo "Image width $width";
    echo "<BR>";
    echo "Image height " .$height;
```

It isnt even displaying the second set of echo's. There are now errors.

Comment: Take out the "return $img", as it stops the script execution from this point. It should work afterwards.

Comment: @Diego If i do that i get the error `Warning: getimagesize(ÿØÿà) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in .............. on line 47
`

Comment: @DiegoAgulló added a function so now the return shouldnt matter.. same issues though.. nothing appears after the function, yet no errors..

Comment: http://php.net/imagick.getsize should do the trick.

Comment: @DiegoAgulló Bingo. Add as answer and ill accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your modifications, you could use the following to get both the width and height:

```
$img = thumbnail($image, $max_width, $max_height);
$width = $img->getImageWidth();
$height = $img->getImageHeight();

var_dump($width, $height);
```

The [getSize](http://php.net/imagick.getsize) method is not documented and its return value is not the one one could expect, so be careful with that!

Answer (score 3):

This code will work

```
$image = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
```

get the file from where ever you want etc. you are using a function with a return value but never set up a var for it to return to. as well you need to save the file in order to use getimagesize.

```
<?
    // $image = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]; // get the file from where ever you want etc
    /*
    you are using a function with a return value but never set up a var for it to return to
    as well you need to save the file in order to use getimagesize


    */
    $image = 'test.png';;

    //Get original dimensions
    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($image);
    echo "<BR>";
    echo "ORIGINAL:";
    echo "<BR>";
    echo "Image width $width";
    echo "<BR>";
    echo "Image height " .$height;



      $max_height = 200;
        $max_width = 150;

     function thumbnail($image, $max_width, $max_height) {
            $img = new Imagick($image);
            $img->thumbnailImage($max_width, $max_height, TRUE);
            return $img;
        }
     // orginal line    thumbnail($image, $max_width, $max_height);
    $img=thumbnail($image, $max_width, $max_height);
    file_put_contents('testmeResize.png',$img );

    //get new dimensions
        list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize('testmeResize.png');
        echo "<BR>";
        echo "NEW:";
        echo "<BR>";
        echo "Image width $width";
        echo "<BR>";
        echo "Image height " .$height;
        // we set it to display the image for proof it works etc
        ?>
        <br>
        <img alt="" src="testmeResize.png">
```