# Image editing with PHP?

Tags: php, image-processing

I would like to be able to crop an image to a 3:2 ratio and then blur the image.

Is this at all possible with PHP without installing any additional classes, as I am on a shared hosting server?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but please remember to always use Google first. A query for `image editing with PHP` or `php image resize` / `php image blur` etc. will give you an overview of what the most common tools are.

Comment: [Resize image using php Imagemagick](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11401039) / [How to achieve a blur effect in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14428257)

Comment: Use [WideImage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I did use Google and for some reason I had thought that PHP classes could not be run on my Hosting Provider. Sorry, I thought StackOverflow was a place to ask questions and get help from those who have more knowledge than oneself. Thanks for the downvote.

Comment: @Ian34, it is indeed a place to get help, but (in common with many sources on the web) a prior coding effort or prior research is politely expected. It helps to explain what you've done already, even if this was fruitless. And, don't take downvotes personally - they are just a form of communication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a library called `GD Library` which will help you to do such stuff.

[A pair of extra eyes could help:](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php)

Comment: You are welcome but a better advice is to Google everything before posting a question

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by additional classes? Image manipulation with PHP requires GD or Imagemagick. I think most hosts have one of these installed.